# Add border to ion-toggle

Tags: ionic-framework

How to add the border around the ion-toggle circle. I see that there is a class `toggle-inner` where we can add the border. However, when I try to override this class, it doesn't take the overridden class. Here is the code that I am using to add the border

```
ion-toggle .toggle-inner { border: 1px solid #ffffff }
```

I have also tried just overriding the `toggle-inner` without the `ion-toggle`. But have no luck with it.

Here is how I am expecting it to look like
 [image]

Here is the ionic library we are using `https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic.js`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Sass](https://sass-lang.com) then you could try setting the `$toggle-ios-border-color-off` variable to the grey you would like as explained [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toggle/Toggle/#sass-variables)

Comment: Unfortunately, we are using less and not sass

Comment: Do not use less, Ionic specifically chose to implement Sass for a number of reasons outlined here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/less-instead-of-sass/1066/2 and so you are just making life unnecessarily harder.

Comment: We are at a point of no return and using SASS is not an option for now. Is there an alternative. Thank you for taking time to respond

Comment: I am not too familiar with less but that's the equivalent variable you want to set

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was unable to set the border. I switched back to normal toggle button instead.